# How can I get a list of files/directories that a user has permission to access in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, permissions

I have a windows service that only runs when it's login credentials are set to a particular user. This service is used to automatically print documents. The user who set the service up has now left but we are currently forced to continue to use his login details. I think the reason this service does not work is because it needs to access certain folders that other credentials do not have permission to access.

I would like to find out which folders the user has access to without having to check the properties of every single folder manually.

I have already tried looking at the permissions in system32/spool/PRINTING

Comment: If you believe this is a user permission problem.  Just grant permissions to  every folder to that user.  I would encourage you to reconfigure the service so you better understand how it works exactly.

Comment: Also, so what is the problem exactly you're seeing. The service just isn't printing to a printer someone or to a folder as PDF, etc.? Check the printer permissions for the printer in question as well as any output folder locations where the final "printed" document goes... Not sure if it's a logical printer or a physical printer...You say you "think" the reason this service does not work is~ but you're not explaining what you see or don't see that indicates the issue. What it supposed to happen exactly? Does that printer allow other documents from others to be printed to it?